# Missing HiveContext Dependency

Tags: scala, hive

I am trying this :

```
val hiveContext = new org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext(sc)
```

This is my build.sbt file :

```
name := "SPARK-SQL"

version := "1.0"

scalaVersion := "2.11.8"


libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" % "spark-core_2.11" % "2.0.0-preview"


libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" % "spark-sql_2.11" % "2.0.0-preview"

libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" % "spark-hive-thriftserver_2.10" % "1.6.2"
```

The Error i am getting :

> Error:scalac: missing or invalid dependency detected while loading
>   class file 'HiveContext.class'.

Comment: Should this class be included in those libraries?

Comment: yes....and it may be like "libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" % "spark-hive-thriftserver_2.10" % "1.6.2" ...but dont know whats going wrong

Comment: Hmmm... Does `spark-hive-thriftserver_2.10` mean "compiled against Scala **2.10** and won't link with other libs compiled against Scala **2.11**"?

Comment: Yes .... but its not working with 2.11 also.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use spark session with hive support in spark 2.0 as below so you simply need spark sql dependency example

```
val spark = SparkSession
  .builder()
  .appName("Spark Hive Example")
  .enableHiveSupport()
```

Answer (score 0):

To work with `org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext`, you need to have following configuration combination in your build.sbt or pom.xml and switch to scala 2.10.6 because of the compatibility issue of spark-hive_2.10:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
    <artifactId>spark-core_2.10</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.0</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
    <artifactId>spark-hive_2.10</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are trying to use the spark-hive library 1.6 with the spark library 2.0, I'm not sure if that works ok.

For Spark 1.6.x you can do:

```
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-hive" % "1.6.3" % "provided"
```